# How to remove skip or pass over conditional where

Tags: c#, linq

In linq I am going to pass in multiple variables. In some of these cases the variables will be null. Is there a way to conditional remove each "where" if var is null? For example:

```
var fooQuery = from s in _db.fooTable
    // var A,B,C,D,E might be null
    where s.a == varA
    where s.b == varB
    where s.c == varC
    where s.d == varD
    where s.f == varE
    select s;
```

If anyone of the variables are null I would like to skip, ignore or pass over that "where".

Let me be more clear.

varA and varB are null so the query would need to change as such:

```
var fooQuery = from s in _db.fooTable
    //Ignore these 2 where because values are null but keep others

    //ignore where s.a == varA
    //ignore where s.b == varB

    where s.c == varC
    where s.d == varD
    where s.f == varE
    select s;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply include the `null` check in the condition:

```
where varA == null || s.a == varA
```

Comment: The downside of this is that the null check is now done on the database server. Not massively important, but worth knowing.

Comment: I see that as an advantage, since the parser can determine that the expression is false on beforehand and just skips it. That is better than wiring all rows over and then check the expression. (Don't see this as disagreement, I do agree it is useful information) @DavidG

Comment: Well the alternative is to build the query up in code, so `if(varA != null) fooQuery == fooQuery.Where(s => s.a == varA);`

Comment: Ah, yes. That is an option too.

Comment: Not hugely beneficial in this trivial example of course, but it can be a "gotcha" in some circumstances :)